# Include stylesheet file into MPDF conversion in PHP

Tags: php, html, mpdf, html-to-pdf

I have made HTML to convert it into PDF using MPDF,
but issue is that I can't include a stylesheet file.

Example:

```
include("../mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyleA4.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

I used the code above but I can't see the effect of the styles.
Does anyone know a better way to include styles?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the stylesheet in the html - it's not clear in your snippet where the content for $html comes from but that's the place to load styles. Using your code you'll be writing the CSS you've loaded as if it were document content for the PDF, which I assume isn't your intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
mPdf works best with inline style sheets which cause no bugs while pdf opens in different browsers.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are setting the new PDF function into "Code" mode. 
    $mpdf=new mPDF('c');

Have you tried it without the "C"?

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
```

Also, is your stylesheet, "mpdfstyleA4.css", located in the same path as mpdf.php?